# How can i write for&if-else statement using only one line?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

- Make List a String: Let's make the list ["Life", "is", "too", "short"] into a "Life is too short" string and print it out.

First, Let me tell you i know the way to solve the problem using join() method.

I wanted to solve this using another method, and i used for statement as below.

```
liszt = ['Life', 'is', 'too', 'short']
restr = ''
for i in liszt: restr += i+' ' if liszt.index(i) != 3 else restr += i
print(restr)
```

How can i correct this in **valid** syntax?
or... is there any simpler way to code this than mine?

At that time, I intended to express same thing as below using one line. But editor told me it's invalid syntax.

```
liszt = ['Life', 'is', 'too', 'short']
restr = ''
for i in liszt:
    if liszt.index(i) != 3:
        restr += i+' '
    else:
        restr += i
print(restr)
```

Comment: one-liner != more readable code

Comment: Consider breaking it down into separate lines one line at a time to see where the interpreter complains. You might be able to pinpoint the problem that way.

Comment: Anyway, the issue is that `else restr += i` should be `else i`

Comment: @DeepSpace yep, right, my bad. It was `liszt.index(i)` not `liszt[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional assignment inside a one-line for loop like this:

```
for i in liszt: restr += i + ' ' if liszt.index(i) != 3 else i
```

Comment: Is there any reason why the if-else statement stick to i+' ' instead of restr += i+' '?

Comment: @benu the statement is not `(restr += ...) if ... else ...` but `restr += (... if ... else ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, one-liners aren't always better/faster/more readable. Here's a solution using `functools.reduce`.

```
from functools import reduce
liszt = ['Life','is','too','short']
restr = reduce(lambda x,y: x + ' ' + y, liszt)
print(restr)
```

Another without importing:

```
restr = ''
for i,word in enumerate(liszt): restr += word + (' ' if i != len(liszt)-1 else '')
```

Another one using the `walrus` operator:

```
restr = ''
[restr := restr + (' ' if i else '') + word for i,word in enumerate(liszt)]
```

Or using the indexing in your question:

```
restr = ''
for i in liszt: restr += i+(' ' if liszt.index(i) != len(liszt)-1 else '')
```

Answer (score 0):

using `recurssion` here is code in one liner

```
nstring = "this is a program running on computer"
nstring = "this is a program running on computer".split()
print(nstring)
# output -> ['this', 'is', 'a', 'program', 'running', 'on', 'computer']
def new_join_method(string): return '' if (len(string) == 0) else f"{string[0]} {func(string[1:])}".strip()
 
solution = new_join_method(nstring)
print(solution)
# output. --> 'this is  a  program  running  on  computer'
```